# Regex: Match string between two determiner that may occur in itself

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regex which escapes a string. The string may occur in it self which should not affect the matching result. Here is my scenario.

My current regex: `(.*?)(.*(\.\$(.*?)\=))(.*\')`

Test strings:

1. `Text.$Property='This: .$Should= be ignored by the regex. Also 'this' shouldn't affect the regex. '`

   - Expected: `'This: .$Should= be ignored by the regex. Also 'this' shouldn't affect the regex. '`
2. It may also be the case that there are multible queries beforehand eg. `Eg.$Over='Other Text'Text.$Property='This: .$Should= be ignored by the regex. Also 'this' shouldn't affect the regex. '`

   - Expected: `'This: .$Should= be ignored by the regex. Also 'this' shouldn't affect the regex. '`
3. `Eg.$Over='Other Text'Text.$Property='Eg.$Over='Other Text'Text.$Property='''`

   - Expected: `'Eg.$Over='Other Text'Text.$Property='''`

So the goal is that no character affects the regex within the expected '--' range. Even if the string itself contains an identical query (see example 3).

**Rules explained verbally**

A overlaying system is interpreting a query.
Example Query:

```
_Children=>Select(@Content.$Placeholder='Some value'._Children=>Select(@SubContent.$Value='Sub value._test of content'))._Count
```

The goal is to match the value within `.$Property='VALUE'`.
In the overlaying query we search just for the last occurrence therefore the match should be `'Sub value._test of content'`.

The problem is that `VALUE` can be any character and any combination and it may occur that `VALUE` is equal to `$Intercept='Just a value'`.
The match which would have been `VALUE` before should now be `$Intercept='Just a value'` without actually affecting the query.

Comment: Examples are of little help. Could you please explain the rules verbally?

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew Of course, i tried to explain it a little better. Hope it helps, if further explanation is needed, please just say so c: Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried `\.\$[^\s=]*='(.*)'`? See https://regex101.com/r/1onXUT/1/

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew something like this but if you have a look at the string: _Children=>Select(@Content.$Placeholder='Some value'._Children=>Select(@SubContent.$Value='Sub value._test of content'))._Count -> it will select $Placeholder='Some value'._Children=>Select(@SubContent.$Value='Sub value._test of content' -> but should actually be .$Value='Sub value._test of content' (and here again: Value between ' ' may contain: 'xyz.$='''. I currently deceided to escape this string but if there is a possible way to do it as I first asked it would be awesome ) and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try `.*\.(\$[^\s=]*='(?!'').*')`, like in `Regex.Matches(s, @".*\.(\$[^\s=]*='(?!'').*')").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`